# Solution for a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a hint for the solution of $y''=\frac{6}{x}y$ without using the power series. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=z \sqrt{6x}$ to make
$$4x^2\, z''+4x\,z'-(1+24x)z=0$$ which is very close to Bessel differential equation.

It would even be more obvious using $x=t^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''-\frac{6}{x}y=0$$
This is an ODE of the Bessel kind.

See Eqs.(6) and (7) in  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

With the notations used in Eq.(6) :

$$\begin{cases}
2\alpha-1=0\\
2\gamma-2=-1 \\
\beta^2\gamma^2=-6\\
\alpha^2-n^2\gamma^2=0
\end{cases} \quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
\alpha=\frac12\\
\gamma=\frac12\\
\beta=2i\sqrt{6}\\
n=1
\end{cases} $$
The solution Eq.(7) is :
$$y=A x^{1/2}J_1\left(2i\sqrt{6}\:x^{1/2}\right)+B x^{1/2}Y_1\left(2i\sqrt{6}\:x^{1/2}\right)$$
$A,B$ are real or complex constants. $J_1$ and $Y_1$ are respectively Bessel funnctions of first and second kind.

Equivalent in real domain :
$$\boxed{y=c_1 x^{1/2}I_1\left(2\sqrt{6}\:x^{1/2}\right)+c_2 x^{1/2}K_1\left(2\sqrt{6}\:x^{1/2}\right)}$$
$c_1,c_2$ are constants. $I_1$ and $K_1$ are respectively modified Bessel functions of first and second kind.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

NOTE :
The original ODE can be transformed to the standard form of Bessel ODE with change of variables : $x=a\:z^b$ and $y(x)=z^c f(z)$ . In putting them into the original ODE one can determine $a,b,c$ so that $f(z)$ be solution of the standard form of Bessel ODE. This is a classical boring calculus.

Comment: Hi Jean ! Long time no speak ! ARe you OK ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi Claude! We live and survive. I see that you continue to do maths. This is rassuring. Cheers.